# Firebase - Group specific type of data and store as single in new table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have below structure for a table in my application with Firebase Database

```
"storePurchase":{
         "$user_id":{
             ".read": "$user_id===auth.uid",
             ".write":"$user_id===auth.uid",
             "$storeId":{
                   ".validate":"root.child('stores/'+auth.uid+'/'+$storeId).exists()",
                   "$pId":{
                       "cId":{
                           ".validate":"root.child('customers/'+auth.uid+'/'+newData.val()).exists()",
                       },
                       "amount":{

                       },
                       "rate":{

                       },
                   }
             }  
        }
 },
```

that stores data as below:

```
{
  "-KeyN0kMSGZbb9hb9lNm" : {
    "-Kf2_5kJoLctmlGcR4d1" : {
      "amount" : "2500",
      "cid" : "-KdChbdoV7nxwZoGLWsY", //cust1
      "rate" : "5"
    },
    "-Kf2_e05toGelnjRMbfg" : {
      "amount" : "10000",
      "cid" : "-KdCggxld52mq0DsGRjH", //cust2
      "rate" : "0.5"
    },
    "-Kf2auWq_hQtTErp55SY" : {
      "amount" : "5869",
      "cid" : "-KdChbdoV7nxwZoGLWsY", //cust1
      "rate" : "58"
    },
    "-Kf2b1QoF4I7LAVAL0_4" : {
      "amount" : "25000",
      "cid" : "-KdChbdoV7nxwZoGLWsY", //cust1
      "rate" : "0.8"
    },
    "-Kf2bEwN5PtwGUec_UFh" : {
      "amount" : "2500",
      "cid" : "-KdCggxld52mq0DsGRjH", //cust2
      "rate" : "0.8"
    },
    "-Kf2b_tZo3rVJbegZNXa" : {
      "amount" : "5000",
      "cid" : "-KdCgJKh6_Rb8MOi-fIj", //cust3
      "rate" : "1.5"
    }
  }
}
```

I am having `cId` i.e. customer ID and now I want to combine these data of each customer and store it in a separate table as unique values. How could I combine these data? I have tried using for loop and tried storing these values on `addValueEventListener` into a separate list, but couldn't get succeeded? How else can I combine these data based on `cId` and sum up the `amount`?

**EDIT**

Am trying to achieve below data structure.

```
"tallyBook":{
      "$user_id":{
            ".read": "$user_id===auth.uid",
            ".write":"$user_id===auth.uid",
            "$storeId":{
                ".validate":"root.child('stores/'+auth.uid+'/'+$storeId).exists()",
                "cId":{
                    ".validate":"root.child('customers/'+auth.uid+'/'+newData.val()).exists()",
                    "totalRate":{

                    },
                    "totalAmt":{

                    },
                },      
            }
       }
 }
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're actually asking. Can you include a JSON example of which data structure you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @PieterLaebens Updated my question with necessary data structure.. Please let me know if you need anything else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this transaction every time that a purchase is placed should keep your tallybook up to date in the way that you want it. So run this transaction every time you push a purchase to Firebase.

```
dbRef.child("tallyBook/"+FirebaseAuth‌​.getInstance().getCu‌​rrentUser().getUid()‌+"/"+storeId+"/"+purchase1.cid).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        TallyBook tally = mutableData.getValue(TallyBook.class);
        if (tally == null) {
            tally = new TallyBook();
            tally.totalRate = purchase1.rate;
            tally.totalAmount = purchase1.amount;
        } else {
            tally.totalRate = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(tally.totalRate) + Double.parseDouble(purchase1.rate));
            tally.totalAmount = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(tally.totalAmount) + Double.parseDouble(purchase1.amount));
        }
        mutableData.setValue(tally);
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
    });
}
```

With Purchase

```
public class Purchase {
    public String rate;
    public String cid;
    public String amount;

    public Purchase() {

    }
}
```

And TallyBook

```
public class TallyBook {
    public String totalRate;
    public String totalAmount;

    public TallyBook() {

    }
}
```

Then you can use the following query to get the tallybook for a particular user and store.

```
dbRef.child("tallyBook/"+FirebaseAuth‌​.getInstance().getCu‌​rrentUser().getUid()‌+"/"+storeId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot tally : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // I called this TallyBook but it's more like one entry in a tallybook
            TallyBook tally = tally.getValue(TallyBook.class);
            // Do something with tally, display it or whatever
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: This is awesome stuff bro. I gotta try this tonight.. I will be having reference till `storeId` level as in `DatabaseReference dbRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("purchase").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(storeId);`. Could you please update the answer as per this reference? Also could you please let me know more about running transaction on every purchase?

Comment: So you want to do it per user/store/purchase? I thought you wanted to migrate all the data you currently already had. I'll change it to where it just updates the tallybook on every purchase. I'll look at it as soon as I can

Comment: No.. I don't want to migrate. Its all new data to be added/updated. There is no production version yet. So I don't have to fear of loosing anything as of now.. :) The functionality is something like, whenever a store owner clicks on **book tally** button, I need to get purchases or all the customers from `storePurchase` table. There might be multiple purchases by single customer and in the `tallyBook` table, I want to merge them all for each customer. Hope its clear. Please do let me know if its not clear yet. and yea please take your time.. :) I'll be waiting..

Comment: Awesome bro.. Thanks much for your time and effort.. I'll implement this tonight and let you know the outcome and accept the answer. Thanks much once again.. :)

Comment: Buddy.. Thanks alot once again.. Can't thank you enough.. Not even a single thing I had to change from your code.. All perfect.. Thank you so much buddy.. :) :)